# error while fetching data from column of type case class in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to explode and retrieve the data but I am getting class cast exception while trying to cast column to case class.
val explodedDF = inputD.withColumn("employee_explode",explode(input.col("employees")))

```
val resultDS = explodedDF.withColumn("first_name", **col(col("employee_explode").asInstanceOf[Employee].first_name**))
```

I am able to explode the employees list but when I am trying to fetch the first_name from Employee, I am getting a class cast exception saying column cannot to converted to type Employee

Comment: my scenario is I wanted to create a column from another column which is an instance of another case class.

Answer (score 0):

The function col returns a Spark Column, and you are trying to build an instance of your Employee from a Column type. To convert data of your dataframes into Spark Types(case classes) you must read about Datsasets or RDDs

Comment: Employee is a nested table and I am getting a list of employees as part of my Dataset which I am trying to flatten it.